# In DNN, When I try to redirect through javascript code getting same page after excution of form submit code

Tags: javascript, html, .net, dotnetnuke

This is my code for submit form, when I click on button perform `Checkout() function`

```
function postURL(url)   {
    var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
        "<input type='hidden' name='CheckedData' value='" + JSON.stringify(CheckedArray) + "'/>" +
        '<input type="hidden" name="URL" value="CQLandingPage" />' +
        '</form>');

    $('body').append(form);
    form.submit();  }

function Checkout()   {
    var CheckOutUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/";
    postURL(CheckOutUrl);

}
```

I want to redirect my page on `CheckOutUrl` but in this case it redirect to same requested page in DNN 
i have applied this code in footer of module from 
**setting > advance setting** of specific module

I have two different domain from request and to response and having one form already in html

Comment: Just so you know, DNN is Asp.Net and it already use <form> tag so you cannot add a Form inside Form.
Try use jQuery Ajax for POST method.

Answer (score 1):

Mitchel Sellers has a blog post about this:

> https://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2007/04/03/allowing-html-form-submissions-from-dnn

The short version is there's *already* an html form element on the page. Adding your own form will conflict with this. However, you can use existing the form, and instead just give your "new" form a button or button-type input element with an `onClick` that uses javascript to change the existing form's action before it submits:

```
<button onClick="this.form.action='YourUrlHere';this.form.submit();">...</button>
```

The downside to this is all of the other inputs on the page will submit (you're submitting the *whole form*). As long as there are no conflicting input names this shouldn't actually break anything; just be aware it may create security or privacy concerns.

Comment: When all you have iin an answer is a link, it's generally good to also write a short summary.